# Remove specific character at the end of each word using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

So far I was able to remove the unwanted character only at the end of the whole string. But I have no idea how to achieve the same result at the end of each word, without removing it at the beginning of each word.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zeqifocewi/edit?js,console) is what I've got.

```
function removeCharacter(str){
  return str.replace(/[!]*$/g, '');
}

console.log(removeCharacter('Hello, my name is Ivan Ivanych.!'));
console.log(removeCharacter("!!Hello there.!!"));
console.log(removeCharacter("Hello,!!! I!! am! Ivan."));
console.log(removeCharacter("!!!Hello,!!! !!I!! !am! Ivan."));
```

Comment: Try `/!(?!\S)/g` or `/!(?!\w)/g`.

Comment: Another idea: `.replace(/(\w)!+/g, "$1")`.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: @Toto,  to have a string without a specific character (exclamation mark in this example) at the end of each word. Avoid removing it at the beginning of the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```js
function removeCharacter(str){
  return str.replace(/([a-z,.])!+/gi, '$1');
}

console.log(removeCharacter('Hello, my name is Ivan Ivanych.!'));
console.log(removeCharacter("!!Hello there.!!"));
console.log(removeCharacter("Hello,!!! I!! am! Ivan."));
console.log(removeCharacter("!!!Hello,!!! !!I!! !am! Ivan."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It will only remove exclamation points at the end of a word.

```js
function removeCharacter(str){
  return str.replace(/(!+)(?=\s|$)/g, '');
}

console.log(removeCharacter('Hello, my name is Ivan Ivanych.!'));
console.log(removeCharacter("!!Hello there.!!"));
console.log(removeCharacter("Hello,!!! I!! am! Ivan."));
console.log(removeCharacter("!!!Hello,!!! !!I!! !am! Ivan."));
```